# How to remove hover effect from a column of a table

Tags: html, css

I'm new in here and this is my first questions in this area.

I've made a table using HTML, CSS. This is the table: http://abidhasan.zxq.net/table/table-others.html

If we keep mouse on a row, hover effect will be happened on that row. Even, if we keep the mouse on a icon/price, the text of the price and the text of the first column will be bold so that it's can easily understand that which column of a which row, I've kept the mouse actually: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q8acafxu3yhefj0/table.png

Everything is fine. But, I've faced one problem.

(1)If I keep mouse on second row, the last column will be also get the hover effect. But, I don't want that. I want, If I keep mouse on second row, the last column won't be hovered.

(2)When I keep mouse on the last column, it'll get hover effect,fine. But, at the same time, second row also get hover effect. I don't want this too. I want that, when I keep mouse on the last column, only the last column will get the hover effect, no other rows/column won't get that hover effect, How, can I do this?

The structure of my table:

```
<table class = "table-4">
  <tr>
      <th>Tapered Triangle</th>
      <th>Diameter 8'</th>
      <th>Diameter 10'</th>
      <th>Diameter 12'</th>
      <th>Diameter 14'</th>
      <th>Diameter 15'</th>
      <th>Diameter 16'</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>      
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td rowspan = "5"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Mainly, I'm facing problem on the second row:

```
<tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>      
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td rowspan = "5"></td>
</tr>
```

and the last column of the second row

```
<td rowspan = "5"></td>
```

Please, if possible, try to give solution by CSS. If it isn't possible by CSS and you give solution with Javascript/jQuery, tell me details kindly as I ain't expert at Javascript/jQuery. If you give solution with CSS3, kindly tell me too how that meet the demand of Cross Browser Compatibility. I'm really new in here. So, please forgive any of my mistake. Thanks to everyone to see my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some small tricks in css and jquery as follows.,

**CSS Part :**

```
<style type="text/css">
.new-child {
background:none !important;
}
.born-child {
background:#d0dafd !important;
}
</style>
```

**jQuery Part :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".table-4 tr:eq(1)").hover(function(){
$(".table-4 tr:eq(1)").find('td[rowspan]').addClass("new-child");
});

$(".table-4 tr:eq(1) td[rowspan]").hover(function(){ 
$(".table-4 tr:eq(1) td").addClass("new-child");  
$(".table-4 tr:eq(1) td[rowspan]").removeClass("new-child");
$(".table-4 tr:eq(1) td[rowspan]").addClass("born-child");
},
function () {
$(".table-4 tr:eq(1) td").removeClass("new-child");
$(".table-4 tr:eq(1) td[rowspan]").removeClass("born-child");
}
);

});
</script>
```

To see it in action : http://jsfiddle.net/john_rock/emtpb/

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: +1 for the `$(".table-4 tr:eq(1)").hover(function(){
$(".table-4 tr:eq(1)").find('td[rowspan]').addClass("new-child");
});`

Comment: Thank you so much, John Peter. I want just that which you've done. Please, help me for the last time about this. I ain't expert at jQuery. I made multiple tables on a page. But,it's only work at the first table. Other tables still have the problem. May be, some new js code should be added.
http://abidhasan.zxq.net/table-test/table-others.html
Please, tell me how can the other tables work like the first table on the page.

Comment: Also, kindly consider that I've made different types table too. So, don't give any default code that hampers other tables(though the css code of that different tables are different) like this: http://abidhasan.zxq.net/table-test/table-aspen.html

Comment: Hi dude i did as per your wish with multiple table option.,now you can use 'n' number of tables with this functionalities.,Please refer the following location : http://jsfiddle.net/john_rock/8jBrM/

Comment: Looking fine. Thanks so much. But, still there are a problem though it isn't any major problem. But, please tell me if you've a easy solution.
After using your new js, If I keep mouse at first at the last column just after loading/refresh the page, the second row still get the hover color.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pyo4pjpwgqx0d8z/4.png
http://abidhasan.zxq.net/table-test/table-others-new.html
But, this not happened after keeping mouse from the second time at that last column. Just happened this if I touch that column without touching others after loading/refresh the page.

Comment: Also, this problem wasn't happened with your old js
http://abidhasan.zxq.net/table-test/table-others.html

Answer (score 2):

remove this css its  in `style.css` near line no 52

```
.table-4 tr:hover td {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #D0DAFD;
    color: #000099;
}
```

you have used `:hover`

> **`:hover`** => Originally invented by Microsoft, the a:hover pseudoclass was an immediate hit. It allows you to define the styles of an element the mouse hovers over.

---

> **Note:** on touch screens :hover is problematic or impossible

**Good Read**

1. [**MDN : `:hover`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:hover)

---

**Edit** 
after your comment

the effect you want can be  achieve by little jquery(javascript) try

remove `.table-2 and 3 and 4 tr:hover td` css

and add little jquery

```
var color = '';
$('td').hover(function(){

    $(this).css('background','none repeat scroll 0 0 #D0DAFD');
     $(this).css('color','#000099');
     $(this).parent().find('td:first').css('background','none repeat scroll 0 0 #D0DAFD');
     $(this).parent().find('td:first').css('color','#000099');


},function(){
    $(this).css('background',color);
     $(this).css('color','#666699');
     $(this).parent().find('td:first').css('background',color);
     $(this).parent().find('td:first').css('color','#666699');
})
```

<sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: @user1896653 i dont understand you want to show only hover first and diameter colon ??? isnt it ?

Comment: Sorry, may be you can't understand my problems
I've already solved the 1st problem:
http://abidhasan.zxq.net/table/table-others-l.html

The 2nd problem is: when I keep mouse on the last column of the second row, that column as well as all of the columns of that second rows will be hovered. But, I want hover only the last column of the second row, not on the other columns of the second row.

Comment: @user1896653 i have tried http://jsfiddle.net/8nfAA/ ...what i understand is in fiddle hope it will helpful for you

Comment: @user1896653 full screen result http://jsfiddle.net/swamimayank/8nfAA/embedded/result/ ...

Comment: @user1896653 you can upvote and accpet  helpful answer ... to accept them you can click on tick mark below voting

Comment: Hi,
Thanks you very much. The work which you've did here: http://jsfiddle.net/swamimayank/8nfAA/embedded/result/ is almost which I want. But, may be still you aren't sure what I want exactly. I've uploaded 3 photos. I hope, after seeing this, you'll be clear. Thanks for your patient and help.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fyfnmsec58w7tu1/1.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4qd0x4s8da4muzj/2.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fgxg7x6qp81oinv/3.png

Comment: @user1896653 there isnt any image ??

Comment: I've given 3 links for 3 photos. Please, see the links:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fyfnmsec58w7tu1/1.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4qd0x4s8da4muzj/2.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fgxg7x6qp81oinv/3.png

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, just have the instructions on each row. Sorry for simple answer, but rowspan will cauce you a lot of greif.

Comment: I've already solved the 1st problem: abidhasan.zxq.net/table/table-others-l.html 
The 2nd problem is: when I keep mouse on the last column of the second row, that column as well as all of the columns of that second rows will be hovered. But, I want hover only the last column of the second row, not on the other columns of the second row.
And rowspan is really obstruct for solving my 2nd problem :(